# php Variable not updating

Tags: php, html, mysqli

the var exists isn't updating its just staying at the initialised value. help please.

```js
    $exists = 0;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from tblUsers WHERE username = '{$username}'");
    if ($result-> num_rows == 1) {
      $exists = 1;
      $result = $mysqli-> query("SELECT email from tblUsers WHERE email = '{$email}'");
      if ($result-> num_rows == 1) $exists = 2;
    } else {
      $result = $mysqli-> query("SELECT email from tblUsers WHERE email = '{$email}'");
      if ($result-> num_rows == 1) $exists = 3;
    }

     if ($exists == 1) echo "<p>Username already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 2) echo "<p>Username and Email already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 3) echo "<p>Email already exists!</p>";
    else {
     // insert data into mysql database
```

Comment: The `->` operator may not have any spaces inside. Your code actually contains syntax errors from the looks of it. Update: you fixed that. Are you sure the user actually already exists?

Comment: Presumably $result->num_rows != 1. Maybe you should find out what value it does hold and check if any errors occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $exists = 0;
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT username from tblUsers WHERE username = '$username'");
    if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
      $exists = 1;
      $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email from tblUsers WHERE email = '$email'");
      if ($result->num_rows == 1)  {
$exists = 2;
}
    } 
else {
      $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT email from tblUsers WHERE email = '{$email}'");
      if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
$exists = 3;
}
    }

     if ($exists == 1) echo "<p>Username already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 2) echo "<p>Username and Email already exists!</p>";
    else if ($exists == 3) echo "<p>Email already exists!</p>";
    else {
     // insert data into mysql database
}
```

I've slightly re written this for my own mind to process it, but my initial thought is that for OO programming you're using a Procedural way of entering data into the database, how about this:

```
   $exists = 0;
        if($object_Var = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username from tblUsers WHERE username = ?")) {
        $object_Var->bind_param("s",$username);
        $object_Var->execute();
     }
        else {
        ///this will run if the script execution failes for whatever reason
        print "error: ".$mysqli->error;
        } 
  if ($object_Var->num_rows == 1) {
           $exists = 1;
           $object_Var_two = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email from tblUsers WHERE email = ?");
           $object_Var_two->bind_param("s",$email);
           $object_Var_two->execute();
          if ($object_Var_two->num_rows == 1)  {
                $exists = 2;
            }
        } 
    else {
          $object_Var_three = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT email from tblUsers WHERE email = ?");
          $object_Var_three->bind_param("s",$email);
          $object_Var_three->execute();
          if ($object_Var_three->num_rows == 1) {
               $exists = 3;
            }
        }

         if ($exists == 1) {
            echo "<p>Username already exists!</p>";
         }
        elseif ($exists == 2) {
            echo "<p>Username and Email already exists!</p>";
            }
        elseif ($exists == 3) {
            echo "<p>Email already exists!</p>";
            }
        else {
         // insert data into mysql database
        }
```

etc etc.

Apologies I havn't done the full script but I think using an OO approach with a OO MySQLi interface should help. Also add `die();` statements into the lines to see where the code reaches for debugging purposes.

I think it would be wise to add in if statments checkin the MySQL executed successfully.